# C++ - function end and local destruction order

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
class Class
{
public:
    std::string Read()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return data_;
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::string data_;
};
```

What will be executed first - will a local copy (temporary) be created of the `data_` string on the stack as a result of the function and then the lock will release the mutex, or will it be other way?

If so, does following line resolve the problem?

```
return std::string(data_);
```

Mutex is supposed to protect concurrent read/write of the `data_`, so that those operations do not interfere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function returns the `data_` as an rvalue, hence the result here will be calculated from the `data_` member before the destructor of `lock` is executed (as the function exits) and the `mutex_` released.

- Is a temporary (the return value) calculated before the mutex is released? Yes.
- Is `return std::string(data_);` required? No.

Comment: Yes, the return value is created "in the code" and the destructor invocation happens "after the code".